# Import a sqlite database from email?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, sqlite

I have got my app to call, the required functions to import my data back in from an email, but I am not sure of the next step. The app gets passed a url but i am un sure as to how i actually going to download that URL into my apps document directory. I am trying to download a.sqlite file. Thank you.

EDIT:Ok, basicly i am having trouble getting my data.sqlite file from my email account back into my app. At the moment, i can select open with my app and that works, i can see the URL of the file but i am unsure how i get the file from that URL into the documents folder of my app so i can do something with it. i have been trying to use

```
NSString *Newpath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/new.sqlite",documentPath];
NSData *backup = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[backup writeToFile:Newpath atomically:YES];
```

where url is the url passed in as run time. Hope that clears thins up a bit. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: you really need to rephrase your question

Comment: Yes please i read it over and over i got nothing.

Comment: @Darc: step by step please: 1. you have an email with an attachment and you want to access it from your app? is that correct?

Comment: Thats correct. 1. i have an email with an sqlite database that i emailed from within my app. 2. i click on it and select open within my app. 3. my app opens and i have a method that gets the URL passed to it. 4. this is where im up to at the moment, i am unsure what to do with the URL (how to download the file that the url points to into my apps documents folder)

Comment: Ok, i feal stupid now, i have had this working fine for the last hour but have been looking in the wrong directory on my mac so i couldnt see the new files being created. To anyone else with this issue, i solved it with this

    NSString* documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *Newpath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/backup.sqlite",documentPath];
    
    NSData *backup = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    [backup writeToFile:Newpath atomically:YES];

sorry for wasting everyones time

Comment: @Darc, please take what you wrote in the comment above and write it in the **Your Amswer** below. thank you.

Comment: will do, have to wait 24 hrs before i can answer my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i feal stupid now, i have had this working fine for the last hour but have been looking in the wrong directory on my mac so i couldnt see the new files being created. To anyone else with this issue, i solved it with this

```
NSString* documentPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]; 

NSString *Newpath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/backup.sqlite",documentPath];

NSData *backup = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
[backup writeToFile:Newpath atomically:YES];
```

sorry for wasting everyones time